# Why isnt my loss function zero when using predictions as training examples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, training-data

I am building a neural network to control a pan tilt gimbal using ROS, OpenCV and Keras. I have position errors and their derivatives presented as the state input, and my approach is to add to the output command position error that resulted from the movement. So my examples are collected as
input(t) -> output(t) + error(t+1) and my understanding is that updates to the network will stop when the error is small.

However, after failing to converge I decided to try removing my error term to verify that my loss is zero. Thinking that what ever the current state of the network, I am passing it training examples that it is already predicting. To my surprise this is still giving me a non zero loss. I feel there is something fundamental that I am missing about how the network trains.

I have put together a minimum working example with a random input, removing the tilt axis for simplicity but otherwise leaving in the basic neural network architecture in case that was where my problem is.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
import numpy as np 

input_dims = 4
batch_size = 4

state_input = Input(shape=input_dims)
initializer = 'glorot_uniform'
x = Dense(128, kernel_initializer = initializer, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1), 
bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), name='neural_inputLayer')(state_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('softplus')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x_pan = Dense(128, activation='softplus', kernel_initializer = initializer, 
kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), name='neural_PantLayer')(x)
mu_pan = Dense(1, activation='linear',kernel_initializer = initializer, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1), 
bias_regularizer=l2(0.01), name='neural_ctrl_output_mu_pan')(x_pan)

model = Model(inputs=state_input, outputs=mu_pan)

OPTIMIZER = optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, clipnorm=0.5, 
clipvalue=0.1)

model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss='mse')
model.summary()

test_inputs = np.array([])
test_outputs = np.array([])

for i in range(batch_size):
    test_input = np.random.rand(input_dims)
    test_output = model.predict(test_input.reshape(1,input_dims))

    #save IO pairs
    if i == 0:
        test_inputs = test_input
    else:
        test_inputs = np.vstack((test_inputs, test_input))

    test_outputs = np.append(test_outputs,test_output)


test_loss = model.fit(test_inputs, 
test_outputs,batch_size=batch_size,verbose=True,shuffle=True,epochs=10)
```

Comment: From the first glance, the most important thing which contributes to loss are l2 regularizers (read what is l2 regularization). The second are, of course, Dropout and batchnorm. Removing all of these gives 1e-13 loss for the first epoch, after that even discrepancies introduced by float rounding errorrs can be magnified by optimizer, which is not plain SGD, but has momentum. Removing optimizer with momentum at last gives what you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I see now that the regularization makes the weights small. I thought regularization affects the rate at which the weights are updated and therefore wouldnt alter training when the error is zero

Comment: L2 regularization penalty is L2 norm of the weights, added to the total loss.

Comment: Dropout is random zeroing of the weights, while batchnorm is frozen during inference and is not updating it's statistics. At last, optimizer with momentum will magnify even slight differences introduced by float precision